# Passing variable from a function to other function from other class - Python

Tags: python, qt, class, variables, pyqt

I already searched possible answers/solutions in my problem but nothing solved it, it doesn't apply in my program. I don't know what's wrong in my code so I want to ask here. I'm using Python 3, Qt.

Here's my code:

## main.py

```
> class Emp(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Emp):
>     def __init__(self, parent=None):
>         #..
>     def getdata(self):
>         ename = str(self.emp_comboBox.currentText())
>         Perform.getrb(ename) 
      @QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_proceed_clicked()")
      def perform(self):
          self.a = Perform(self)
          self.a.show()
          self.close()
  class Perform(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Perf):
>     def __init__(self, parent=None):
>         #..    
>     @QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_procbutton_clicked()")
>     def getrb(ename):
>         print(ename)
```

## output

```
> Fatima Cruz *prints the ename*  
> <__main__.Performa at 0x00000000036EC288>`
```

EDITED:
Before, my prblem was to pass variable 'ename' from class Emp to class Perform. My problem now is the

```
> <__main__.Perform object at 0x00000000036EC288>
```

I don't know what does it mean and how to debug that.

I hope this all makes sense. Let me know if you need clarification. Any criticism is welcome concerning the code itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you identified precisely which line is causing the problem?

Comment: Hi Sir, I already get the 'ename' but there is still an error I think. Because after the 'ename', the output also has '<__main__.Perform object at 0x00000000038DC288>' What does it mean?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It's not runnable as it is and therefore people here can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution I think you should change `Perform.getrb(self, ename)` by `self.getrb(ename)`?

Comment: I tried it but I get the same output. Thanks for answering. anyway, I forgot some code, I'll edit it maybe that part has the problem. Please see it :)

Answer (score 0):

So the reason that you don't provide a runnable code is really not good. But for your question: 'What does it mean'

If you have a class lets say:

```
#main.py
class A:
    #some methods

classA = A()
print class A
```

--> Output: __main__.A object at 0x00... (some more numbers)
If you print an object Python will tell you what class it belongs to:
__main__A --> Object of class A in main module
and at 0x00... tells you where it is stored in memoery.

So in your code you may have statement where you print an object

Comment: Sorry for that. Hehe but Thanks! :)